# Find element in the center between toggle button [Upvote/Downvote/unvote like SO]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to find this element between toggleClass. This is I've tried so far. 
This is my JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/8rrctstf/12/

I should get the element `vote_count`.

*HTML*

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="vote upvote" data-product_id="12" href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
    </a>
    <span class="vote_count">100</span>
    <!-- FIND THIS -->
    <a class="vote downvote" data-product_id="12" href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

*JQUERY*

```
$('.vote').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');

    alert($(this).next().text()); // TRIED SO FAR

    $(this).siblings('a.vote').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        // alert(product_id + ' :unvote');
        $.get("{{ URL::route('unvote') }}", {
            product_id: product_id
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    } else {
        if ($(this).hasClass('upvote')) {
            // alert(product_id + ' :upvote');
            $.get("{{ URL::route('upvote') }}", {
                product_id: product_id
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        } else {
            // alert(product_id + ' :downvote');
            $.get("{{ URL::route('downvote') }}", {
                product_id: product_id
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
How to do increment(+1), decrements(-1), reset(0)

**EDIT2**
my answer since this increment on js seems so hard.

```
$('.vote').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');

    var voteCount = $(this).siblings('.vote_count');

    $(this).siblings('a.vote').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        // alert(product_id + ' :unvote');
        $.get("{{ URL::route('unvote') }}", {
            product_id: product_id
        }).done(function (data) {
            voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
        });
    } else {
        if ($(this).hasClass('upvote')) {
            // alert(product_id + ' :upvote');
            $.get("{{ URL::route('upvote') }}", {
                product_id: product_id
            }).done(function (data) {
                voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
            });
        } else {
            // alert(product_id + ' :downvote');
            $.get("{{ URL::route('downvote') }}", {
                product_id: product_id
            }).done(function (data) {
                voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `siblings` method

```
$(this).siblings('.vote_count')
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/0ok78wmc/)

```js
$('.vote').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Cache votecount element jQuery object
  var $voteCount = $(this).siblings('.vote_count');

  // Get the votes count
  var count = +$voteCount.text();

  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    // When unvoting, if previous vote is upvote then decrement it by one
    // If previous vote is downvote then increment it by one
    $voteCount.text($(this).hasClass('upvote') ? --count : ++count);
  } else {
    if ($(this).siblings('a.vote').hasClass('active')) {
      $voteCount.text($(this).siblings('a.active').hasClass('upvote') ? count - 2 : count + 2);
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('upvote')) {
      // Increase vote count by one
      $voteCount.text(++count);
    } else {
      // Decrease vote count by one
      $voteCount.text(--count);
    }
  }
  $(this).siblings('a.vote').removeClass('active');

});
```

```css
.vote {
  color: Black;
}
.active.upvote {
  color: green;
}
.active.downvote {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <a class="vote upvote" data-product_id="12" href="#">
    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
  </a>
  <span class="vote_count">100</span> 
  <a class="vote downvote" data-product_id="12" href="#">
    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you extend it with the count of the current votes? increment or decrement and reset when unvote

Comment: it's bugged, try upvote, then downvote, then unvote. the result become 101 instead 100

Comment: @StormSpirit Just now updated it! please check again

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer given by @Tushar, I have updated your fiddle to insert the count of the current votes into the spans based on up or down vote. It is up to you as to how you want to initially populate the number in your HTML.

```
$('.vote').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var curVal = parseInt($(this).siblings('.vote_count').html());     

    $(this).siblings('a.vote').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');   
    if( !$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).siblings('.vote_count').html(curVal--);
        alert('unvote ');
    } else {
         if( $(this).hasClass('upvote')){
             $(this).siblings('.vote_count').html(curVal++);
            alert('upvote ' + curVal);
         } else {
            alert('downvote ' + curVal);
             $(this).siblings('.vote_count').html(curVal--);
         }

    }
});
```

Here is a link to an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sed5t847/

Comment: @buzzaw it's wrong, try this test, when you click downvote, then click downvote again. The value should be 27 not 25.

Comment: @Storm Spirit You are correct. I didn't take that into account when putting this together. Tushar has an updated answer that address it though so I will leave mine as is to not detract from his correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not query the span by class specifically:

```
alert($('.vote_count').text());
```

If you have multiple places people can vote you could modify the query to something like:

```
alert($(this).parent().children('span').text());
```